# Convex optimization: what is atom library?

Tags: convex-optimization, cvx

By reading the CVX users' guide, I frequently [came across](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html) with the term "atom library", which I suppose to be a set of functions that one must use to construct mathematical expressions on solvers. But this definition is not clear to me, let alone how the atom library relates with the DCP ruleset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding new functions to the CVX atom library just means adding new functions which can accept CVX variables and expressions as input, as described in the section [Adding new functions to the atom library in the CVX Users' Guide](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/advanced.html#adding-new-functions-to-the-atom-library), thereby expanding CVX's capability.

For instance, CVX has `log_sum_exp`.  You could add a `log_sum_inv`function to the atom library by implementing the formulation for [Log-sum-inv in section 5.2.7  of the Mosek Modeling Cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/expo.html#modeling-with-the-exponential-cone).